# Quarterly Date calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem on scheduling jobs on the first date of the last month of each quarter.
This would be very easy as I can get the last month of every quarter and then append the first date to it like

```
select START_DATE,
CONVERT(datetime,CAST(YEAR(START_DATE) as VARCHAR(4))+'/'+
                 CAST(DATEPART(Q,START_DATE)*3 as VARCHAR(2))+'/01 00:00:00',120
       ) as SCHEDULE_DATE_LAST_MONTH_OF_QUARTER
from JOB_SCHEDULE_CONFIGURATION
```

The stumbling block is the START_DATE. I will illustrate with an example

```
START_DATE SCHEDULE_DATE_LAST_MONTH_OF_QUARTER
2012/05/01 2012/06/01 --correct schedule
2012/02/15 2012/03/01 --correct schedule
2012/06/15 2012/06/01 ---problem at this line I will explain why
```

The start date happens to be 2012/06/15 and I cannot schedule a job prior to the start date ie 2012/06/01. I have to schedule it only after 2012/06/15 that means the job should be scheduled on the next quarter ie 2012/09/01

How should the query be modified? I think there might be some math involved and I really don't excel in math.
Please help.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  START_DATE date
)

insert into @T values
('2012-05-01'),
('2012-02-15'),
('2012-06-15')

select dateadd(month,
               2,
               dateadd(quarter,
                       datediff(quarter,
                                0,
                                dateadd(month,
                                        case when day(START_DATE) >= 15
                                          then 1
                                          else 0 
                                        end,
                                        START_DATE)),
                       0))
from @T
```

**Update:**

The main part of this query is to get the first date of a quarter and that is done by the dateadd/datediff trick.

```
select dateadd(quarter, datedifF(quarter, 0, START_DATE), 0)
from @T
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

You wanted the last month of the quarter so we add a `dateadd(month, 2`

```
select dateadd(month, 2, dateadd(quarter, datedifF(quarter, 0, START_DATE), 0))
from @T
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

That leaves only the part where dates later than the 15th of the last month should be in the end of the next quarter. `day(START_DATE)` will give you the day of the month so we can add 1 month to START_DATE if `day(START_DATE) >= 15` using a case statement.

```
select dateadd(month, case when day(START_DATE) >= 15 then 1 else 0 end, START_DATE)
from @T
```

Result:

```
----------
2012-05-01
2012-03-15
2012-07-15
```

Putting it all together it will look like this.

```
select dateadd(month, 2, dateadd(quarter, datedifF(quarter, 0, dateadd(month, case when day(START_DATE) >= 15 then 1 else 0 end, START_DATE)), 0))
from @T
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: can you please explain the logic behind the query. Thanks PS START_DATE can be any date from 1st to 31st. It does not have to be 15.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. Got it. Super. Thanks for the query and the detailed explanation

Comment: Shouldn't it have >= 1 instead of >= 15? For jobs with start dates that have a day from 2 to 14 of the month (for instance '2012-06-14')  it's not going to display next quarter.

Comment: @Ivan__83 - You might be right about that and I might have read the question wrong. It looks like `15` was only a sample date and not the tipping point. Any way, your fix will take care of that.

Comment: It's just a minor consideration, your solution is really good and optimal.